# How to put content beside Image using XSL-FO in a PDF?

Tags: xsl-fo

I am trying to create a sample PDF, I wish to achieve what as shown below [[image: Image1]] , i.e , my page is divided in 2 halves, one half contain image (blue color) and has content just beside it. But my code is generating what is shown below [image: Image2], i.e, the content is starting from below of the image not beside.

Below is my sample code:-

```
<xsl:template match="SAMPLE">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
          <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="30cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="0cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.2cm" margin-right="0.2cm">
                    <fo:region-body column-count="2" column-gap="5mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
          </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                 <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block margin-left="3.5%" margin-right="3.5%" margin-top="4%" margin-bottom="2%" >   
                                <fo:block margin-left="2cm">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="D:\PDF\Image1.jpg" width="5cm" height="6cm" scaling="uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </fo:block>

                                <fo:block top="2%" color="#154360" margin-top="4%">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="MyPage/ImageQuote/Quote"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
```

Any help how I can achieve this?

Comment: Your image is confusing. Do you want the text to be "under" the image or do you want the text to flow around the image? If you want it to flow around it, you are looking for fo:float to float the image to the left.

Answer (score 2):

As Kevin says, the goal is not clear. If you want to flow text around the image, it is needed to use fo:float/@float="start". Here are sample XSL-FO and formatted image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="30cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.2cm" margin-right="0.2cm">
            <fo:region-body column-count="2" column-gap="5mm" border="1pt solid black" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block-container margin-left="3.5%" margin-right="3.5%" margin-top="4%" margin-bottom="2%" >
                <fo:block color="#154360" start-indent="0mm" end-indent="0mm">
                    <fo:float float="start">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic src="Image1.jpg" width="3cm" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>&#xA0;&#xA0;
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:float>
                    <fo:block>
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[image: Formatted result]

Comment: thanks, I wanted the text to be around the image, not under it. Thank you